# How to fix Admob Unsupported Language issue?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

Admob has limited ad serving for my apps due to 'Unsupported Language'. I need to know if there is a way to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This page lists the languages that Admob currently supports:

- [Languages Google publisher products support](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9727)

If your pages' content is primarily in an unsupported language, then Google Publisher Policies do not allow you to embed Google ad code in them.

### Why the restriction?

Since your language is not supported, that means that Google probably does not allow advertisers to submit advertisements in your language.  So there would be no adverts in your language to show to users of your app.

If Admob showed advertisements in languages different to your content, the chances are that users of your app wouldn't read and click through the ads.  And *some* proportion of users would complain about being shown "inappropriate" ads.  So your embedded Admob code would be a drain on Google's infrastructure (and human resources to deal with the complaints) ... for no return to Google.

### Why don't they support your language?

Commercial / business reasons, I guess.

### Possible solutions?

1. Write your apps to serve content in a different (supported) language<sup>1</sup>.
2. Remove the Admob code from your app<sup>2</sup>.
3. Investigate alternative ways of showing ads in Google app.

Do a search for "alternatives to admob" or "alternatives to adsense". There are a number of possible alternatives, though it will depend on the language your content is written in.

---

<sup>1 - This is self-defeating if your primary goal is to serve up  content written in the (unsupported) language.

2 - This is self-defeating if your primary goal is to get ad revenue.</sup>

Comment: But in some other apps in same language , admob showing ads

Comment: Maybe the authors of those apps have added some other languages as well.  But talk to Google.  This is primarily a question about Google's business policies ... not programming.

Answer (score 1):

The Google page is clear (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9727?hl=en):

> Placing Google ad code on pages with content primarily in an unsupported language is not permitted by the Google Publisher Policies.

I think the only way to fix this is to add a supported language to your contents